# Definition of Derivative variations

Tags: real-analysis

Assuming $f'(c)$, I need to find the following limits:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(c-h)-f(c)}{h}$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(c+nh)-f(c)}{h}, \quad n \neq 0$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(c+h^2)-f(c)}{h^2}$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following transformations $k=-h $ , $k=nh$  and  $k=h^2$ respectively and in view of

$ k\to 0$ as $h\to 0$ in all cases , you should get the following :

$A=-f'(c)$

$ B=nf'(c)$

$C = f'(c)$